# Comprobar respuesta de un formulario tipo test a, b, c, d

Tags: python, django

Tengo un formulario con una pregunta y 4 respuestas posibles. El usuario selecciona la respuesta y pulsa responder. Debe mostrar la web si la respuesta es correcta o no.

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la vista tengo la consulta de la pregunta, posibles respuestas. Se muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al seleccionar el usuario una respuesta y pulsar el botón responder se debe comprobar. **¿Dónde se hace la comprobación? ¿En views? ¿En models? ¿Cómo?** En la vista tengo la consulta de respuesta buena, etc. Pero no se cómo y dónde hacer la comprobación y hacer que se muestre la comprobación al usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué deberíamos poner en action=""? ¿Debe apuntar a un def de views?

Answer (score 0):

Eso lo pudes hacer declarando una view control de respuesta por ejemplo del estilo:

```
def control_respuesta(request):
    controlo_respuesta()
```

Luego, en url tienes que poner algo para que Django asoscie el evento a la vista.
Por ùltimo en el botón debes llamar a la función (ya sea por ajax o submit).

De todas formas te recomiendo seguir este instructivo:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: ¿Te refieres en añadir ese def dentro de views.py? En este caso qué deberíamos poner en action="" y en method="" para que lleguen ahí los datos? Gracias.